# What is archive-contents and how do I create it?

Tags: package-repositories, package-development, cask

I used `cask package` to generate a package tar file for my local fork of `ensime`, and added it to my `package-archives` using `customize-option`. However, I then got this backtrace when attempting to `list-packages`:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-error "Opening input file" "no such file or directory" "/home/hackthetower/ensime-emacs/dist/archive-contents")
  insert-file-contents("/home/hackthetower/ensime-emacs/dist/archive-contents")
  package--download-one-archive(("hackthetower" . "/home/hackthetower/ensime-emacs/dist") "archive-contents")
  #[0 "\301\300\302\"\207" [("hackthetower" . "/home/hackthetower/ensime-emacs/dist") package--download-one-archive "archive-contents"] 3 "\n\n(fn)"]()
  funcall(#[0 "\301\300\302\"\207" [("hackthetower" . "/home/hackthetower/ensime-emacs/dist") package--download-one-archive "archive-contents"] 3 "\n\n(fn)"])
  package-refresh-contents()
  list-packages(nil)
  call-interactively(list-packages record nil)
  command-execute(list-packages record)
  helm-M-x(nil "list-packages")
  call-interactively(helm-M-x nil nil)
  command-execute(helm-M-x)
```

Indeed, this `archive-contents` file mentioned in the backtrace doesn't exist. How am I supposed to create it?

Comment: Maybe rather than try to create a tar file that you can then install via `package-install`, you'd be better served to try and create directly an installed package (i.e. create directly the package's directory in `~/.emacs.d/elpa/`).  IOW let Cask install the package.

Answer (score 1):

That file is created by `package-upload-file`, but unfortunately that function has [a bug](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=19800) in Emacs 24.4.1 that means it does not work in this scenario.